# IBTOOL error 255 in XCODE 5 / work fine in XCODE 4

Tags: xcode, ibtool

I want to open and compil my project in XCODE 5 and i have an issue. IBTOOLS error 255. Does anybody have a idea for fix ? 
I try all the answered of StackOverFlow, but nothing was good for the case.

Alex.

```
    CompileStoryboard Safetracer/MainStoryboard.storyboard
    cd /Users/alexandrepestre/Documents/ThinkMyApp/Lixao/Safetracer
    setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/.."
    /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/alexandrepestre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safetracer-bdnzaaahcuqikggnpqlvwvrsbddt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/safetracer.app/MainStoryboard.storyboardc /Users/alexandrepestre/Documents/ThinkMyApp/Lixao/Safetracer/Safetracer/MainStoryboard.storyboard

2013-09-13 16:07:15.433 ibtoold[4775:707] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Documents/IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer.m:324
Details:  Failed to push inherited simulated metrics to all scenes.
Object:   <IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer: 0x7f969aab4ad0>
Method:   -rebuildInferredMetrics
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9699c191b0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-13 16:07:19.057 ibtoold[4775:707] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Documents/IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer.m:324
Details:  Failed to push inherited simulated metrics to all scenes.
Object:   <IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer: 0x7f969dacc750>
Method:   -rebuildInferredMetrics
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9699c191b0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-13 16:07:30.797 ibtoold[4775:707] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:670
Details:  Failed to compile nib consisting of IBProxyObject, IBProxyObject, IBProxyObject, IBProxyObject, IBUIButton, IBUIButton, IBUIButton, IBUIButton, IBUIButton, IBUIImageView, IBUIImageView, IBUIImageView, IBUIImageView, IBUIImageView, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, and IBUIView.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Exception reason: NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value
Exception backtrace:
  0. CoreFoundation           0x0226e5c8 __exceptionPreprocess
  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x01fed8b6 objc_exception_throw
  2. CoreFoundation           0x0226e3bb +
  3. Foundation               0x01be48c0 -
  4. Foundation               0x01be4761 -
  5. UIKit                    0x00ee50f6 -
  6. UIKit                    0x00ee54c7 -
  7. UIKit                    0x0112fa96 -
  8. UIKit                    0x011303e3 -
  9. UIKit                    0x0112f6b4 -
 10. UIKit                    0x0112fa96 -
 11. UIKit                    0x011303e3 -
 12. UIKit                    0x00d8995b -
 13. UIKit                    0x0112fa96 -
 14. UIKit                    0x011303e3 -
 15. UIKit                    0x0112f6b4 -
 16. UIKit                    0x0112fa96 -
 17. UIKit                    0x011303e3 -
 18. ???                      0x00014c80
 19. ???                      0x00014e4e
 20. ???                      0x00015363
 21. ???                      0x00007565
 22. IBFoundation             0x00360701 __72-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:result:]_block_invoke
 23. IBFoundation             0x00360446 -
 24. IBFoundation             0x00360123 __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:]_block_invoke
 25. libdispatch.dylib        0x029c3444 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
 26. libdispatch.dylib        0x029d44b0 _dispatch_client_callout
 27. libdispatch.dylib        0x029c2766 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
 28. CoreFoundation           0x022d3a5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
 29. CoreFoundation           0x0221472b __CFRunLoopRun
 30. CoreFoundation           0x02213b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 31. CoreFoundation           0x0221394b CFRunLoopRunInMode
 32. Foundation               0x01c23c05 -
 33. ???                      0x00036b67
 34. ???                      0x00036c62
 35. ???                      0x00036dc7
 36. ???                      0x0000c20e
 37. libdyld.dylib            0x95727725 start
Exception info:{
}

Function: void IBAssertMarshallingFailure(NSString *__strong, NSString *__strong)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9699c191b0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010d20ff2a -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010d20f684 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010d20f984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000112774df6 IBAssertMarshallingFailure (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x000000011285b59a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x000000011285ba0d (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000011286b445 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000011286f4b0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000011287063e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000010c64c40a IBWithAutoInvalidationPool (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10  0x0000000112870363 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 11  0x0000000112856316 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 12  0x000000011285683c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 13  0x000000010c39b2fe __47-[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x000000010c3be250 -[IBDocument assertIfArbitrationIsScheduledDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x000000010c39b272 -[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x000000010c17c757 (in ibtoold)
 17  0x000000010c17fc21 (in ibtoold)
 18  0x000000010c18a23d (in ibtoold)
 19  0x000000010c18a781 (in ibtoold)
 20  0x000000010c18a654 (in ibtoold)
 21  0x000000010c188ade (in ibtoold)
 22  0x000000010c189eb2 (in ibtoold)
 23  0x000000010c189610 (in ibtoold)
 24  0x00007fff8be7a7e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 25  0x0000000000000001
Command /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
e
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. 

Answer (score 8):

It appears that ibtool is not able to handle a storyboard created with an earlier xcode version where the text attribute can be omitted on a UILabel. Easiest way to fix is to open the storyboard in your editor of choice and add the missing text attributes, text="".

Comment: Your answer is correct. Just for clarification in case someone else is confused by the wording: an empty attribute text="" is fine, it's only a problem if the attribute is not there at all.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the bugs. There is 2 label on viewController with no text in tne textlabel. I put some text (Label) and now the app build and run well.

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed through re-ceate xib resource with xcode5.

Answer (score 0):

I hate Xcode for this type of thing.

Most of the ibtool error get solved just by `clean`ing the project and then `rebuild`ing it.