# ibtool failed with exit code 255 when i use UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uidatepicker, build-error

My Xcode and Simulators are working perfectly until,
I add Date picker from Library, build a program and it shows error "ibtool failed with exit code 255"

I have tried.

1. Refreshing the project.
2. Refreshing the Xcode.
3. Refreshing the machine.
4. changing of IOS 6.1 to 5.1 and vice versa.
5. Deleting of Drived Data from Windows --> Organizer --> Projects

almost everything i checked out in previous posts but still helpless.

Comment: Probably worth checking this answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788963/ibtool-error-255-in-xcode-5-work-fine-in-xcode-4-resolved

Comment: Nope not worked ... problem isn't in my storyboard but in date picker @PhilRyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re installing Xcode solved my problem :)

1. Drag Xcode to trash from Launchpad
2. Go to the app store and install it again.